# Load <li> tag on their own status

Tags: jquery, html, css, grails

I on grails project (2.4.0) I got a form with navigation bar like this (page1-page2-page3-page4-page5)
Each of them have three status: active, normal and required
so, here my code:

```
<li class="${session.navigation.agreement == 0 ? 'normal' : 'required'}"
                onclick="$('#appForm').attr('action', 'agreement').submit();
                return false;"></li>
```

my default, `session.navigation.agreement = 0`

How can I add a class active to active page?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by adding a class active to class="active" page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a replacement variable and separate it from the exisiting with a whitespace

```
<li class="${session.navigation.agreement == 0 ? 'normal' : 'required'} ${yourIndicatorForActive ? 'active' : ''"
```